# Об отчествах

Tags: имена-собственные

Увидела на одном сообществе интересный вопрос. Народ там не пришел к единому мнению, поэтому хочу задать его тут.
Иногда родители дают детям самые невообразимые имена. В том числе двойные. Например: Владимир-Геннадий. А как от такого имени будет образовываться отчество?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Из Кодекса о браке и семье:** "Отчество присваивается только по имени лица, указанного отцом ребенка. В случае двойного имени у отца отчество ребенку присваивается **по одному из имен либо в слитном написании обоих имен отца** (пункт 2 статьи 63)"

Comment: Вообще-то практика двойных имен пришла к нам из Европы, где отчеств как раз и нет. Две традиции взаимоисключающие, так сказать :-) Так что родителям, прежде чем они дадут имя мальчику, надо задуматься, какое же отчество будет у их внуков :-)

Comment: Согласна. Именно потому, что двойные отчества не в нашей традиции, их правописание и склонение нигде не описано. (Или описано, и я просто не встречала?)

Answer (score 1):

Да, бедные дети! Уважаемый алёха, а какие это законы русского языка Вы имели в виду?

Answer (score 1):

Владимиргеннадьевич отчество будет, если сохранять оба имени.
Но если его папа будет чуточку адекватнее дедушки и бабушки, то Владимирович.
Второе имя даже в русской традиции играло неофициальную или вспомогательную роль.
Правда это совсем другая история.

Comment: Ну да, в слитном написании если )))

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю о кодексе, но по законам русского языка будут склоняться оба имени, и отчество будет Владимирович-Геннадьевич.

Comment: Сразу возникает двусмысленность. Вы не находите? :-))